# Change Thumb-Drawable of SeekBar once progress excedes 10%?

Tags: android, seekbar

Im trying to change the thumb drawable of a seekbar once the progress is over 10%.. but the thing is..
that once the progress hits > 10, the thumb-drawable "disappears".. is this some know bugs or is it just as simple as this aint supposed to be possible?

Here is my code:

```
    public class SliderTestActivity extends Activity {
    SeekBar sb;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        sb.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fingerprint));
        sb.setProgress(50);
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                seekBar.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.egg));

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                if(progress > 10)
                {
                    sb.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.egg));
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the net:

```
final Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.egg);
d.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()));
slider.setThumb(d);
```

The thumb doesn't disappear, however after the change it behaves a bit strange. It doesn't stop at the begin and end of SeekBar and half of it is hidden.

Edit:
It seams that setThumb also sets thumb offset to half width. By setting offset to 0 after you set the thumb you can make it behave like original thumb:

```
slider.setThumb(d);
slider.setThumbOffset(0);
```